# Laravel 5.2 Authentication Token

Tags: php, laravel, rest, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement a Token based authentication in Laravel 5.2. What I've done is:

**Routes.php**

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth:api']
], function() {
    Route::get('/api/reservation', 'apiController@get');
});
```

I've modified the **User** model and added the `api_token` field and added a new user with a random string via `seeders`:

**Migration**

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('api_token', 60)->unique()->nullable()->default(null);
        });
```

**Seeder**

```
User::create([
            ...,
            'api_token' =>  str_random(60),
        ]);
```

**Controller**

```
class apiController extends Controller
{
    function get(Request $request) {
        return Reserva::all();
    }
}
```

Then, In `Postman` I try to GET the url adding `/api/reservation?api_token=xxxxx` with the token I have in the database but I always get *Unauthorized*. Something weird is if I do a `dd($this->auth)` on the authentication middleware I get a `TokenGuard` object with the `name='web'`. Isn't It supposed to be `api`?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, can you guys give me a hint? Thank you

Comment: Do you want to use Laravel Passport?

Comment: If I can get it to work without external libraries it would be perfect. Otherwise I'll use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else face this problem. My problem was In the `Authenticate` middleware. I had an old version somehow.

I had this `Authenticate` middleware:

```
class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And I solved it by changing it with this:

```
class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return rediresct()->guest('login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `auth:api` middleware you are using uses Laravel Passport. You cannot use it if you want a custom token based authentication like you do where you create your own tokens.

If you want to use Passport, do this:

Keep your routes like that. The routes that require authentication must be inside of the `auth:api` middleware.

You can remove the `api_token` field of your `users` table. The `$table->rememberToken()` function in the migration is completely different than the API token you think of. In fact, tokens are not stored in the database at all. The token you see in the `oauth_access_token` table in the database is not the token you use for you HTTP requests.

Do NOT create a custom token like you do. Check that the login/password couple of the user is valid, generate a token and return it to the consumer of the API like that:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['login' => $req->login, 'password' => $req->password])) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $token = $user->createToken('ToutelaBreizh')->accessToken;
    return response()->json(['token' => $token],200);
}
```

Beware to place the login/register routes OUTSIDE of the `auth:api` middleware, otherwise you would need to give a token to a route that is supposed to give you this token - it makes no sense.

Next, make sure you send the token to the API in the `Authorization` header of the request, and not in the request parameters like you do. Add in Postman the following header:

```
Authorization: Bearer your_token_retrieved_before
```

Now you're pretty much done, you can use your API with Postman.

Comment: Would I store the token somewhere within the browser or would I have to keep sending the token back?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I don't want a `registration/login` logic in the API, I just want the authorization. The idea under this is I want someone external to the app to be able to do a `POST` to an url and save some data in the database. My thoughts were I had to give that Token to te client and he would be able to do the `POST` request

Comment: @Vilius You are not supposed to consume an API with your browser, an API is more intended to mobile apps, but let's say you want to make a website that get its content from an API, you would have to call the login route, retrieve the token, store it in the storage of the browser like `localStorage` and each time you make a call to the API you send the token in the header. The API is stateless, it is not supposed to store the token so that you don't have to resend it each time.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi , sorry that is what I've meant, thanks for the advise. I was struggling with `VueJs` which is mixed with `laravel` the other day

Comment: It's not about getting content from API to render a website. It's about storing data in both web applications through an API call. They store some data in their website and we have to have it too, so they make a post request to our application and the data gets consumed and saved in our application. Maybe I'm not explaining myself.

Comment: @Alberto I can't seem to the see the benefit of having a token based authentication without login/register routes. If everybody can use your API any way they want, place all your routes outside of the `auth:api` middleware.

Comment: Also everythinkg I've found on Internet points to this way of Token authorization. For example: [styde.net](https://styde.net/autenticacion-basado-en-token-en-laravel-5-2/), [gistlogs](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51)

Comment: Hey, I posted the solution I've found, the problem was I had an old `Authenticate` middleware somehow.